# Sharing memory in NodeJS and Express application

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to understand Node/Express a little better and was wondering if it was possible for one request to overwrite the memory of another. Here's a contrived example:

```
// UserController.js
const userService = require('./UserService');

class UserController {
  async show(req, res)  {
    userService.userId = req.params.userId;
    const userDetails = await userService.getDetails();
  }
}
module.exports = UserController;

// UserService.js
const request = require('request-promise');

class UserService {
  set userId(userId) {
    this._userId = userId;
  }

  async getDetails() {
    // Make HTTP request to some service
    let options = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://url-to-user-service/' + this._userId, // Notice use of userId
      json: true,
      headers:{}
    };

    return request(options);
  }

}
const userService = new UserService(); // pseudo-singleton
module.exports = userService;
```

Is it possible to have 2 concurrent requests do something like this:

Request1: execute line "userService.userId = req.params.userId" // userId 1

Request2: execute line "userService.userId = req.params.userId" // userId 2

Request1: execute line "const userDetails = await userService.getDetails();" which would have a userId of 2? Or will the entire show() function be executed for request 1 before request 2 would execute it?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you forget an `async` in `show` declaration ?

Comment: Yes I did - I'll fix it (sorry, this was a contrived example I came up with on the fly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is, your code is buggy and it will bite you when you have several requests coming fast.

Here:

```
  async show(req, res)  {
    userService.userId = req.params.userId;
    const userDetails = await userService.getDetails();
  }
```

While node waits for the results of `userService.getDetails()`, yes you can have another parallel execution, total or partial, of the `show` function.

This feature lets your program be more efficient, especially when `userService.getDetails` appends to be slow. Of course if you access some shared data from the function then you need to think about the possible inconsistencies which may occur.

I can't redesign your program without knowing more but a simple solution could be to have an instance of `UserService` or an object having the same role kept in the scope of `show`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm coming from a Java/Spring world where all our "service" beans are singletons - and so we try to make them stateless. The better solution would be to pass the userId to userService.getDetails(userId) - I think that would fix it. In Node, do you try to reuse the same service instances so you're not instantiating new objects for every request, or do you not worry about that and just instantiate a new service for each request? If userService was instantiated in the show function, would another request not be able to overwrite the values?

Comment: "Service" is an ambiguous world. Both in Java and JavaScript it doesn't really make sense to try avoid allocating a few objects for every requests, both engines are fast enough.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - that makes sense.